# Java methods manipulate two objects attributes value return wrong. Bank transfer program

Tags: java

The Transfer method encountered some problems. When I execute the testclass java file. `A1` balance will become the same as `A2`as 28. It also pop up `You balance is insufficent.`
I should expect A1 be 69, A2 be 28, and no insufficient warning.
What's wrong with the `transfer` method?

```
public class account {
    public static String id;
    public  static String name;
    private  static int balance;

    public account() {id = "Null"; name = "Null"; balance = 0;}

    public account(String id, String name, int balance) {
        this.id = id; this.name = name; this.balance = balance;}
            
    public int getbalance() {return balance;}

    public void credit(int amount) {
        int newbalance = balance + amount;
        balance = newbalance; }

    public void debit(int amount)
    {
        if (amount <= balance) {
            int newbalance = balance - amount;
            balance = newbalance;}
        else { System.out.println("You balance is insufficent.");}  
    }
}
```

Next one is the testaccount class.

```
public class testaccount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        account A1 = new account("A101", "Tan Ah Teck", 88);
        account A2 = new account("A102", "Kumar",9); // default balance   
        transfer(A1,A2, 19);
    }
    public static void transfer(account from, account to, int fee) {
        from.debit(fee);
        to.credit(fee);
        System.out.println(from.getbalance());
        System.out.println(to.getbalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove static from your variables.BTW: take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character.

Comment: Problem solved. I Thank you.  Can you tell me why I need to remove static?

Comment: `static` on a field makes it a class field that is shared by all instances.

Comment: Read about static keyword in the java documentation.